# error with python qt message box

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, messagebox

The messagebox keeps 'flashing' :s. It doesn't crash, but it just keeps on opening and re-opening. How could I fix this problem?

```
self.retranslateUi(Login)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ExitButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), Login.close)
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.LoginButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.get_value_from_user)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Login)
    Login.setTabOrder(self.LoginButton, self.UsernameEdit)
    Login.setTabOrder(self.UsernameEdit, self.PasswordEdit)
    Login.setTabOrder(self.PasswordEdit, self.ExitButton)

def get_value_from_user(self):
    Correct_details = False
    while Correct_details==False:
        inputusername=self.UsernameEdit.text()
        inputpassword=self.PasswordEdit.text()
        cur.execute("SELECT password FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
        password=str(cur.fetchone())
        password=password[2:-3]
        cur.execute("SELECT firstname FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
        FirstName=str(cur.fetchone())
        FirstName=FirstName[2:-3]
        cur.execute("SELECT surname FROM tblStaff WHERE username='"+inputusername+"'")
        Surname=str(cur.fetchone())
        Surname=Surname[2:-3]
        if str(password) == str(inputpassword):
            self.msgBox1 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information,'Successful', "Succesfully Logged in")
            self.msgBox1.show()
            Correct_details = True
        else:
            self.msgBox2 = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, 'Warning', "The Username or Password you have entered is incorrect")
            self.msgBox2.show()
```

Comment: Can you please show when/where get_value_from_user is called?

Comment: yeah, its called when the login button is pressed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program logic is wrong. Inside the `get_value_from_user()` method, you have the line `while Correct_details==False:`. This is the line that is causing the problem. Once the user has entered their incorrect login details, they don't get the option to enter them again, you just repeatedly read out the same login details from `self.UsernameEdit` and `self.PasswordEdit` and of course the continue to not be correct, and so the loop runs forever and each iteration of the loop, you pop up the message box saying they are incorrect.

The loop mentioned above needs to be somewhere else in your code (possibly in the method that calls `get_value_from_user`), that allows the user to re-enter their username and password. The `get_value_from_user()` method should probably return the variable `Correct_Details` so that the calling method can decide whether to present the user with the login form again, or proceed.

Comment: thanks alot man, yeah, i just cleared the lineedit so they can re-enter the username and password, and used a break if they entered it wrong:)
btw, do you know how to connect to different widgets? i have been reading a lot around the subject, but find it hard to understand any of them. i have two different widgets in two different .py files, i want to open the other one if the login is successful in this one :S

Comment: @Thaz probably best to post that as another question on SO